# How to segue multiple view controllers programmatically using swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm getting an error:

> has no segue with identifier 'dest1''

and what I did was:

- route(ctrl+drag) in storyboard  viewcontroller -> dest1, viewcontroller -> dest2
- have an action button in viewController.swift
- set storyboard ids to "dest1" and "dest2"

  ```
  @IBAction func Parameters(_ sender: AnyObject) {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dest1", sender: nil)
  }
  ```
- Prepare for segue

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {
      print("0")
      if segue.identifier == "dest1" {
          if let svc = segue.destination as? secondViewController {
              print("1")
          }
      } else if segue.identifier == "dest2" {
          if let svc = segue.destination as? reverbViewController {
              print("2")
          }
      }
  ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you added the segue identifier to the storyboard? That error usually means there is no segue from the current view controller with that identifier. Check that the view controller you are calling performSegue from actually has a segue with that identifier.

Comment: I did, look http://imgur.com/a/mL4sk

Comment: That is your storyboard id, not segue id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, you have set storyboard ids to "dest1" and "dest2", whereas you need to set segue identifiers. Click on the segue itself in IB, and set it's property.

Storyboard identifiers are used when creating the view controller using code...

```
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController")
```

Comment: I added this  in the viewdidload storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dest1")
and it didnt worked

Comment: As I mentioned above, and what Michael said, that isn't the segue identifier, that's the storyboard id. This is a segue identifier -> http://www.scott-sherwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/SetSegueIdentifier.png